# expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef' - one H file with a typedef of a struct while its fields are written in another H

Tags: c, struct, header-files, typedef

i'm receiving the next error:

expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef' (*in challenge_room_system_fields.h*):

This is challenge_system.h:

```
typedef struct SChallengeRoomSystem
{

#include "challenge_room_system_fields.h"

} ChallengeRoomSystem;
```

This is challenge_room_system_fields.h:

```
#include "challenge_system.h"

typedef struct SChallengeRoomSystem //this is where i get the error
{
    char* system_name;
    struct Challenge* challenges;
    int numOfChallenges;
    struct ChallengeRoom* rooms;
    int numOfRooms;
    int timeOfLastAction;

} ChallengeRoomSystem;
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

I know its not the best way to deal with structs but as a school assignment i'm required not to change the challenge_system.h. I am allowed to change only challenge_room_system_fields.h

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can't nest `typedef` like that, AFAIK.  You certainly shouldn't.  It also appears you have infinitely recursive includes — `challenge_system.h` includes `challenge_room_system_fields.h` and `challenge_room_systems_fields.h` includes `challenge_system.h`, and there's no multiple-inclusion protection shown, so things go badly haywire.  You need to reorganize your thinking and your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Are the quotes complete? I have a feeling that somewhere reinclusion guards should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should've just write the following inside challenge_room_system_fields.h :

```
    char* system_name;
    struct Challenge* challenges;
    int numOfChallenges;
    struct ChallengeRoom* rooms;
    int numOfRooms;
    int timeOfLastAction;
```

The reason is that the #include by definition takes the included file and Copy-Pastes it instead of the line I wrote #include...

so eventually challenge_system.h will look as follows:

```
typedef struct SChallengeRoomSystem
{

// this is where previously i had: #include "challenge_room_system_fields.h"
//now i will have the following:

        char* system_name;
        struct Challenge* challenges;
        int numOfChallenges;
        struct ChallengeRoom* rooms;
        int numOfRooms;
        int timeOfLastAction;

} ChallengeRoomSystem;
```

And now it works:)